# Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'long'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, type-conversion, syntax-error

Here's the first portion of my code, which declares `technology` and give's it a value of `1.0` :

```
 static void Game1()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            Int64 startingCash = random.Next(4000, 5000);
            Int64 startingVillagers = random.Next(4, 13);
            double technology = 1.0;
            Console.WriteLine("Your starting villagers are " + startingVillagers + ", and your starting cash is " + startingCash + ".");
            Console.ReadLine();
            MainGame(startingCash, startingVillagers, technology);
        }
```

And here is the second part of my code, where the error is occurring, here, the `tecnology += 0.5` causes the error. :

```
 else if (probability >= 7 && probability <= 10)
                {
                    technology += 0.5;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your tech has increased, you now have " + technology + " Tech points.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
```

I've tried using `long`, `Double` and `double`, yet I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: What does the method definition of `MainGame` look like?

Comment: Is that second code snippet part of the `MainGame` method? The `technology` variable being used there is not the same variable declared in the first snippet because that's a local. We need to see the declaration of the actual variable/parameter being used in that second snippet.

Comment: There is no problem with this your code, probably the problem is with the second function. Please show body of MainGame

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature of the MainGame method from this:

```
static void MainGame(Int64 startingCash, Int64 startingVillagers, long technology)
```

to this:

```
static void MainGame(Int64 startingCash, Int64 startingVillagers, double technology)
```